# Google Maps markers not visible on deployed version but are available on local run version

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps

I'm using react-google-maps for my app. The map and markers work when running locally. However in my deployed version on Vercel, the map is there- but not the markers. The way I'm defining the markers is through a mapping similar to:

```
{propertyLocalTest.map((property)=>( 

                        <Marker
                        key = {property.slug}
                        icon = {icon}
                        
                        position={{ 
                            lat: parseFloat(property.fields.latitude),
                            lng: parseFloat(property.fields.longitude)  
                        }}
                        />
                    ))}
```

In another project I noticed img attributes I had given opacities of 60%, being constantly set to opacity 1% when deployed; this was an easy fix- changing % to decimals. I'm thinking something similar is occurring as an individual hardcoded marker (with Lat and Lng) will show up, but when an array of hardcoded lat and lngs is mapped to a `Marker` element these will **only show up locally**, and **never** when deployed.

I don't have the luxury of inspecting the individual markers within a google map to confirm if this is in-fact the problem.
Are there any recommendations on how to diagnose/solve the problem?

In summary: All functionality will work as expected when running locally, **but only individual markers that are **not** mapped** will appear when the app is hosted.

My question: Are there any obvious discrepancies between deployed react apps and apps running locally?

Comment: Did you check console? Any errors or warnings?

Comment: None appearing that are related to this component. I have one for a deprecated package, but I'm not using that at all in this side of the app.

Comment: I mean in browser console. I'm using this package too with a 1000 markers and no problem.

Comment: ahh, there is one that is related to the maps: Warning: Legacy context API has been detected within a strict-mode tree.

The old API will be supported in all 16.x releases, but applications using it should migrate to the new version.

Please update the following components: withGoogleMap(MapContainer)

Comment: not too sure why it would work locally however... I'll try and solve this. I assume your markers are mapped using the same package no problem?

Comment: yes, update to a new versions and everything should be fine. The another problem could be with icon path. It resolves in different ways on dev and prod

Comment: Thank you. I think I've tried with the default markers before and no change in result, but will go through with the updating

Comment: What steps would you take to update the package's props yourself? I've found the file but quite confused as to what it should actually entail

Comment: I'm using `@react-google-maps/api` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Unfortunately the problem is still persisting! I've successfully transferred to `@react-google-maps/api` and also changed markers to default ones: again working locally- but I deploy and no markers except the non-mapped one. Really confused as to what is causing this. And all console errors have disappeared which is a plus but old issue remains

Comment: what's your `propertyLocalTest` data and what's your `icon` data?

Comment: `propertyLocalTest` is an array structured like this:  `const propertyLocalTest =[
{fields: {longitude: "-1.619226", latitude: "55.006889"}},
{fields: {longitude: "-1.610750", latitude: "54.975522"}} ]` and `icon` is a file pathway to the icon I'm using

Comment: what exactly path?

Comment: should be like that: `icon="/images/icon.svg"` where `images` is a folder inside `public` folder

Comment: I'll try the structure you've given for pathway. But I think it won't change as even when **not** adding an `icon` the markers still won't show up deployed

Comment: icon should has relative path right from public folder, especially if you are using create-react-app and made prod build.

Comment: I get the console error `Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../public/images/addressresize.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.`

Comment: If it worked locally why wouldn't it when deplyed?

Comment: because webpack prod build overrides main path. You should use exactly `/public/images/addressresize.png`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216918/discussion-between-yahms23-and-demkovych).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working: was not using the mapping function and instead calling a custom function that uses a `for` loop instead of mapping and returns/renders the outputs.